# How do I remove the selected row/item from QListWidget?? (Python/PyQt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I wanted to know how i could remove the current selected row/item in a QListWidget??

I used the code below with no luck! Although it returns no error, nothing happens? :

```
self.QuestionList.takeItem(self.QuestionList.currentRow())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`takeItem` takes the *row count* as parameter, which can be retrieved using `listWidget.row()` method.

```
for item in self.QuestionList.selectedItems():
    self.QuestionList.takeItem(self.QuestionList.row(item))
```